# Is there monotonicity of measure concentration?

Tags: pr.probability, measure-concentration

Suppose $X$ and $Y$ are nonnegative random variables such that $\mathrm{Pr}(X\geq t)\leq\mathrm{Pr}(Y\geq t)$ for all $t\geq0$. Now take $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ to be independent with the same distribution as $X$, and similarly for $Y_1,\ldots,Y_n$ with $Y$. I would like to know if the following is necessarily true:
$$
\mathrm{Pr}\bigg(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nX_i\geq t\bigg)\leq\mathrm{Pr}\bigg(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nY_i\geq t\bigg) \qquad \forall t\geq0.
$$
By assumption, it's true for $n=1$. For large $n$, the sample averages will approach $\mathbb{E}[X]$ and $\mathbb{E}[Y]$, respectively, which satisfy
$$
\mathbb{E}[X]
=\int_0^\infty\mathrm{Pr}(X\geq t)~dt
\leq\int_0^\infty\mathrm{Pr}(Y\geq t)~dt
=\mathbb{E}[Y].
$$
So intuitively, the inequality of interest should also hold for large $n$. Can anything funny happen for moderately sized $n$?

(As the title suggests, I'm interested in this as a tool analyze measure concentration.)

Comment: Slightly tongue-in-cheek: with distributions like Cauchy or Levy the sample averages will not approach the means.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, it is true for any $n$. The easiest way to see it is by using the fact that your condition means precisely that $X$ and $Y$ can be realized on the same probability space $\Omega$ in such a way that $Y\ge X$.

Comment: So $X$ and $Y$ don't need to be nonnegative?

Comment: No, they don't. By the way, if your $X$ and $Y$ are compactly supported, one can always make them positive just by adding an appropriate constant.

Comment: Can something be said when all (X_i) and (Y_i) are assumed to be independent?

Comment: @Joris Bierkens: No. Let $\overline X= (X_i)$ and $\overline Y = (Y_i)$ be the corresponding sequence valued random variables. The question involves just the distributions of $\overline X$ and $\overline Y$, but not their joint distribution.

Comment: @R.W. - If we realize $X$ and $Y$ in the same probability space, can't we draw the $X_i$'s and $Y_i$'s with $2n$ independent outcomes of the probability space? I think the difficulty would not be independence between the $X_i$'s and $Y_i$'s, but rather a more exotic joint distribution.

Comment: @Dustin G. Mixon: I can just repeat my previous comment. The way you formulated the problem it only asks about distributions of $\overline X$ and $\overline Y$ separately, so that their joint distribution is irrelevant.